# How do I remove this extra kite from the diamond in this code?

Tags: python

I have written a python program for printing a diamond. It is working properly except that it is printing an extra kite after printing a diamond. May someone please help me to remove this bug?  I can't find it and please give a fix from this code please.
CODE:

```
limitRows = int(input("Enter the maximum number of rows: "))
maxRows = limitRows + (limitRows - 1)
while currentRow <= limitRows:
    spaces = limitRows - currentRow
    while spaces > 0:
        print(" ", end='')
        spaces -= 1
    stars = currentRow
    while stars > 0:
        print("*", end=' ')
        stars -= 1
    print()
    currentRow += 1
while currentRow <= maxRows:
    leftRows = maxRows - currentRow + 1
    while leftRows > 0:
        spaces = limitRows - leftRows
        while spaces > 0:
            print(" ", end='')
            spaces -= 1
        stars = leftRows
        while stars > 0:
            print("*", end=' ')
            stars -= 1
        print()
        leftRows -= 1
    currentRow += 1
```

OUTPUT(Case 1):

```
D:\Python\diamond\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Python/diamond/main.py
Enter the maximum number of rows: 4
   * 
  * * 
 * * * 
* * * * 
 * * * 
  * * 
   * 
  * * 
   * 
   * 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

OUTPUT(Case 2):

```
D:\Python\diamond\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Python/diamond/main.py
Enter the maximum number of rows: 5
    * 
   * * 
  * * * 
 * * * * 
* * * * * 
 * * * * 
  * * * 
   * * 
    * 
  * * * 
   * * 
    * 
   * * 
    * 
    * 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Side note, your code would probably be much easier to read/debug of you were using functions to separate the abstract steps of the logic (e.g. one function for a diamond of arbitrary size, another one to print several diamonds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra while loop in the second half of your code.

Try this

```
limitRows = int(input("Enter the maximum number of rows: "))
maxRows = limitRows + (limitRows - 1)
currentRow = 0
while currentRow <= limitRows:
    spaces = limitRows - currentRow
    while spaces > 0:
        print(" ", end='')
        spaces -= 1
    stars = currentRow
    while stars > 0:
        print("*", end=' ')
        stars -= 1
    print()
    currentRow += 1
while currentRow <= maxRows:
    leftRows = maxRows - currentRow + 1
    spaces = limitRows - leftRows     # Removed unnecessary while loop here
    while spaces > 0:
        print(" ", end='')
        spaces -= 1
    stars = leftRows
    while stars > 0:
        print("*", end=' ')
        stars -= 1
    print()
    leftRows -= 1
    currentRow += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this less complex by using just one loop as follows:

```
def make_row(n):
    return ' '.join(['*'] * n)

rows = input('Number of rows: ')

if (nrows := int(rows)) > 0:
    diamond = [make_row(nrows)]
    j = len(diamond[0])
    for i in range(nrows-1, 0, -1):
        j -= 1
        diamond.append(make_row(i).rjust(j))

    print(*diamond[::-1], *diamond[1:], sep='\n')
```

**Example:**

```
Number of rows: 5
    *
   * *
  * * *
 * * * *
* * * * *
 * * * *
  * * *
   * *
    *
```

Comment: I don't understand the ":" thing.

Comment: @WasifShahzad I think you're referring to := which is the so-called "walrus" operator that was introduced in Python 3.8